# Jquery cannot toggle MDL check box when in ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, checkbox

I want to toggle a [google material design lite (MDL)](http://www.getmdl.io/) checkbox based on ajax post results, but it seems not working.

Then I did some testing: I found that either normal checkbox or out of ajax would work. And the actual value of failure checkbox is changed, but UI keeps unchanged.

Codes here：
`

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

A1<input type="checkbox" id="A1" value="A1"><br>
A2<input type="checkbox" id="A2" value="A2">
<hr>
B1
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="B1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="B1" class="mdl-switch__input">
    <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</label>
B2
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="B2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="B2" class="mdl-switch__input">
    <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</label>

<script>
    console.log('initial');
    console.log('->'+$('#A1').is(':checked') + $('#A2').is(':checked')
            + $('#B1').is(':checked') + $('#B2').is(':checked'));
    // now toggle the 4 checkbox; A2 and B2 under post funciton
    $("#A1").prop("checked", true);
    $("#B1").prop("checked", true);
    $.post("#", function (data) {
        console.log("...");
        $("#A2").prop("checked", true);
        $("#B2").prop("checked", true);
        console.log('after toggle');
        console.log('->'+$('#A1').is(':checked') + $('#A2').is(':checked')
                + $('#B1').is(':checked') + $('#B2').is(':checked'));
    });
</script>
`
```

or [codepen online](http://codepen.io/qing6010/pen/gPezQM?editors=0000). Check box A1,A2,B1 working. B2 not working but its value is true (refer to browser console).

Did I forget something or is it a bug? Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: I guess there are 2 possible reasons. ① The material.min.js only run once when creating elements. ② the webpage theme use material.min.js  to update the UI and is blocked under post (for security).

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround for myself. I use trigger('click') instead, this will call the mdl javascript (though I did not read them) to update css.

Since a simulation of click event will conflict with itself (leads to an infinite ajax request loop when there is a click-trigger in click), a detection of mouse/program event needs to be used.
sample codes below:

```
 $('#checkbox').click(function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (event.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
    //manual click
    $.post("#", {a: 0}, //post something to server
       function(data) {
      console.log('!! a post request !!!');
      target = data;//...parse the target from ajax result
      ($this.is(':checked') !== target) && $this.trigger('click');
    });
  } else {
    //program click
    console.log('++program++');
    $this.trigger('click');
  }
});
```

When calling from program, codes below:

```
  $.post("#", {a: 0}, function(data) {
    console.log('!! a post request !!!');
    target = data;
    ($('#checkbox').is(':checked') !== target) && $('#checkbox').trigger('click');
  });
```

So with these codes, either a manual click or a program click will only call ajax request exactly once.